# ng-form inside ng-repeat with submit button outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I've  this code:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="input in inputs | filter:inputNumber">
     <ng-form name="form1">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input ng-model="inputs.number[$index]" type="number" name="number$index" class="form-control" placeholder="" min="1" max="9999" required />
                     <small class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && form1.number$index.$error.required">required</small>
                     <small class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && form1.number$index.$error.number">number</small>
                     <small class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && form1.number$index.$error.max">number max</small>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ng-form>
  </div>

 <button data-ng-click="add(form1)" class="btn-add" style="padding-left: 40%;"></button>
```

Controller:

```
// Form add handler.
$scope.add = function(form) {
    // Trigger validation flag.
    $scope.submitted = true;

    // If form is invalid, return and let AngularJS show validation errors.
    if (form.$invalid) {
        console.log('invalid');
        return;
    } else {
        var newItemNo = $scope.inputs.length + 1;
        var inputs = { 'id': 'input' + newItemNo }
        $scope.inputs.push(inputs);
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
    }
};
```

The problem is I can only validate the form inputs inside ng-repeat and ng-form, and I need to trigger the event outside of that html block, maybe I'm just being noob (first time using angular1 validations). I will appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But this code generates N forms with name "form1" where N is the number of items in your ng-repeat (`inputs`). You can not validate `form1`, since `form1` are many forms (all of them with the same name). Please, correct me if I'm wrong so I can help you

Comment: Do you wanted to submit a form only when all forms are valid?

Comment: Yes @Asiel , this generates forms with the same name, I can make the name dynamic with $index, but I need to validate al the forms when a submit is clicked outside of the ng-repeat.

Comment: Why don't you put the `form` tags around the entire set of your current forms, so it becomes a single form with a single submit

Comment: @cale_b Because that will add an invalid input to the array before validating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you comment and following the same goal of generating a form for each element in your ng-repeat, this should be the answer:

**html**

```
<form name="generalForm"> <!-- this form will be valid if all sub-forms are valid-->
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="input in inputs | filter:inputNumber">
     <ng-form name="form1">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input ng-model="inputs.number[$index]" type="number" name="number$index" class="form-control" placeholder="" min="1" max="9999" required />
                     <small class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && form1.number$index.$error.required">required</small>
                     <small class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && form1.number$index.$error.number">number</small>
                     <small class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && form1.number$index.$error.max">number max</small>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ng-form>
  </div>

 <button data-ng-click="add(generalForm)" class="btn-add" style="padding-left: 40%;"></button>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
// Form add handler.
$scope.add = function(form) {
    // Trigger validation flag.
    $scope.submitted = true;

    // If form is invalid, return and let AngularJS show validation errors.
    if (form.$invalid) {
        console.log('invalid');
        return;
    } else {
        var newItemNo = $scope.inputs.length + 1;
        var inputs = { 'id': 'input' + newItemNo }
        $scope.inputs.push(inputs);
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm glad to help ;)